# How many possible combinations using 4 select fields

Tags: math

I have four `HTML` select fields

[image]

How can I find the different number of combinations that a user can make by setting 0,1,2,3 or all 4 `fields`. I want make `switch cases` for the selected `parameters`.

**EDIT :**

For instance the user can select

Category , channel , region , country

```
OR
```

Category , channel , region

```
OR
```

Category , channel

```
etc ...
```

Comment: If you have respectively n1, n2, n3 and n4 choices for each field, and the choices are independent, the number of combinations is just the product of the number of possibility for each field i.e. 1 for 0 open fields to n1*n2*n3*n4 for 4 fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [combinations and permutations](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/discrete-mathematics-and-probability/permutations-and-combinations) if you want a deeper understanding of the math but if I understand you correctly you just want a basic amount of combinations when you can choose one of each:

If order doesn't matter then you use the formula `P(n,r)=n!(n−r)!`

Where `n` is the amount of choices and `r` is how many you can choose but since it's combo boxes you'll just use `r=1` and n is the options and multiply each answer with all the others.

So in this case you'll just multiply the amount of choices of each combo box to get the total.

e.g. `5 Categories * 4 Channels * 10 Regions * 2 Countries` = `400 choices`

**Edit:**

If a field is optional it just means it has an extra option i.e. to not specify a value which means you just need to add `1` to each value i.e.

If Categories and Channels is optional:
`(5+1)*(4+1)*10*2` = `600` choices

If all of them are optional:
`(5+1)*(4+1)*(10+1)*(2+1)` = `990` choices

If you want to use a `switch` consider putting each field in it's own `switch` for simplicity (then the number of `switch` statements will be equal to the number of fields and the sum of the `case` keywords the sum of the options for all the fields (including no option)

Have a look at [combinations and permutations](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/discrete-mathematics-and-probability/permutations-and-combinations) if you want a deeper understanding of the math but if I understand you correctly you just want a basic amount of combinations when you can choose one of each:

If order doesn't matter then you use the formula `P(n,r)=n!(n−r)!`

Where `n` is the amount of choices and `r` is how many you can choose but since it's combo boxes you'll just use `r=1` and n is the options and multiply each answer with all the others.

So in this case you'll just multiply the amount of choices of each combo box to get the total.

e.g. `5 Categories * 4 Channels * 10 Regions * 2 Countries` = `400 choices`

**Edit 2:**

If a field is optional it just means it has an extra option i.e. to not specify a value which means you just need to add `1` to each value i.e.

If Categories and Channels is optional:
`(5+1)*(4+1)*10*2` = `600` choices

If all of them are optional:
`(5+1)*(4+1)*(10+1)*(2+1)` = `990` choices

If you want to use a `switch` consider putting each field in it's own `switch` for simplicity (then the number of `switch` statements will be equal to the number of fields and the sum of the `case` keywords the sum of the options for all the fields (including no option)

**Edit 3:**

If you just want to know the amount of fields the person can choose (not values) e.g. the person can choose to fill in Category and Channel you're going to use combinations:

`C(n,r)=n!(n−r)!r!`

There are 4 options and you can choose none + There are 4 options and you can choose 1 ... (`n` is choices and `r` is how many you can choose)

`C(4,0)+C(4,1)+C(4,2)+C(4,3)+C(4,4)`

`4!/(4-0)!0! + 4!/(4-1)!1! + 4!/(4-2)!2! + 4!/(4-3)!3! + 4!/(4-4)!4!`

`1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 16`

Also have a look at [Binomial theorem](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/binomial.htm). It fits nicely with this problem

Comment: I think you have confused the question & that's my bad. Please see the edit, I have made my requirement clearer.

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan so each field is optional or are some of them mandatory? Also can a user select no field at all as well?

Comment: Yes a user can select all 4 , either 3 , either 2 , only one or no field at all. And don't take into consideration whats inside a field

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan So do you just want to know how many combinations of field choices the person can have? (e.g. Option 1 = Just field 1, Option 2 field 1 and 2, etc.)

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan okay I'll add it to the answer. For 4 fields it will be 24. Check the answer for more details.

Comment: Your answer is taking repetition into consideration, isn't it ? Of course my case demands without  repetition

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan Sorry accidentally forgot to add the last one. Fixed it. Check the new answer.